# How to Customise the Extent Report by removing unwanted graphs and Extra space

Tags: extentreports, selenium-extent-report, extent

is there a way to remove Steps Graph and Logs Graph From the extent report and customise the layout. (Need to remove the graphs in the highlighted in red)
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFp2E.png)

Updated Issue: I was able to hide the unwanted graphs using the configuration.xml file

```
  <!-- custom javascript -->
    <scripts>
        <![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(function() {
            document.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-12 col-md-4")[1].style.setProperty("display","none");
            document.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-12 col-md-4")[2].style.setProperty("display","none");
            document.getElementsByClassName("col-md-3")[1].style.setProperty("display","none");
            });
        ]]>
    </scripts>

    <!-- custom styles -->
    <styles>
        <![CDATA[

        ]]>
    </styles>
</configuration>
```

but now the graph layout is not nice.. there are lots of unwanted blank space.
is there a way to fix the layout issue

[Updated Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYyYw.png)

Comment: Are you using C# or java? And which version of the extent report are you using? I am also facing similar issue

Comment: I'm using Java and extent report version is 4.1.5
I managed to resolve this using the java script in the first answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hate to reply for the my own question :)
but found a way to do this using java script.
in the extent report configurations add the following line to resize the Test results graph

```
 sparkReporter.config().setJS("document.getElementsByClassName('col-sm-12 col-md-4')[0].style.setProperty('min-inline-size','-webkit-fill-available');");
```

Comment: Even easier is to remove the class col-md-4.